# Counter Example to "naive" Dominated Convergence Theorem for Outer Integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

To provide some context, given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, and for an arbitrary map $T: \Omega \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$, the outer expectation is defined as

$$
E^*T = \inf\{ EU \: : U \mbox{ is measurable,} \; U \ge T\}.  
$$
Let $\Omega= [0,1]$, $\mathcal{F}$ the standard Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $P$ uniform measure on $[0,1]$. It is stated in Van Der Vaart and Wellner, Empirical Processes with Applications to Statistics, that there exists a sequence of maps $T_n: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ so that $T_n \downarrow 0$ everywhere, but $E^*T_n =1$ for all $n$, providing a counter example to "Naive Outer Dominated Convergence". This is stated on page 13 without proof. Could someone think up what counter example they had in mind here?

Comment: In this case $T_n$ is not bounded by 1-- they claim an example exists where $T_n:[0,1] \to [0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to assume the [Axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice). Let $V$ be a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) : a subset of $[0,1]$ such that, for each real number $r$, there is exactly one number $v\in V$ such that $v−r$ is a rational number. Then $V$ is not Lebesgue measurable and has inner measure $0$ (i.e. its complement has outer measure $1$).

Let $(q_k)$ be an enumeration of rationals ; we define

$$
V_n := \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n (V+q_k)\right) \cap [0,1].
$$

Now let $T_n \colon [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be the characteristic function of the complement of $V_n$ : namely,

$$
T_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if $x \in V_n$} \\
1 &\text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}.
$$

Then we have $T_n \downarrow 0$ everywhere, since $\displaystyle\bigcup_n V_n = [0,1]$. Furthermore, each $V_n$ has inner measure $0$ which means that $E^*T_n =1$.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Tristan!